# build tree from two arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

How to code to build a binary tree if we have given two arrays which represent how the corresponding nodes are connected. It is given that the root of the tree starts from element 1.

```
Ex -> arr1[] = {1,1,5,8,25}
      arr2[] = {4,5,8,6,5}

                               1
                             /   \
                            4     5
                                 / \
                                8   25
                               /
                              6
```

Comment: Is it a binary tree?

Comment: yes it is a binary tree

Answer (score 1):

Use a map to store the node corresponding to each number, that will simplify the task. The algorithm would look something like this:

```
# initialise the map
map = {}
for element in arr1:
    if element not in map:
        map[element] = new_node()
for element in arr2:
    if element not in map:
        map[element] = new_node()

# each node will have a data value, and left/right pointers to children
for i in range (len(arr1)):
    parent, child = arr1[i], arr2[i]
    if map[parent].left == None:
        map[parent].left = child
    else map[parent].right = child
```